# stderr undeclared identifier

Tags: c

```
void
argmatch_valid (const char *const *arglist,
            const char *vallist, size_t valsize)
{
  size_t i;
  const char *last_val = NULL;

  fprintf (stderr, _("Valid arguments are:"));
  for (i = 0; arglist[i]; i++)
    if ((i == 0)|| memcmp (last_val, vallist + valsize * i, valsize))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "\n  - `%s'", arglist[i]);
      last_val = vallist + valsize * i;
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf (stderr, ", `%s'", arglist[i]);
    }
  putc ('\n', stderr);
}
```

I am getting the following although I have included stdio.h in my .c file

```
warning C4013: 'fprintf' undefined; assuming extern returning int

error C2065: 'stderr' : undeclared identifier

warning C4013: 'putc' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

I thought of disabling the warning by #pragma warning( disable :4013 ) but wanted to compile the code clean.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I keep on wondering... The OP knows about pragmas but not about stdio.h

Comment: @icepack I am getting the following although I have included stdio.h in my .c file

Comment: I have already included stdio.h

Comment: You have an invalid character: `_` in `fprintf (stderr, _("Valid arguments are:"));`. Remove it

Comment: Removed that..still no luck

Comment: The posted code is valid without the invalid character `_` and with included `<stdio.h>` and `<memory.h>`. Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: "FILE *stderr;
#include <Stdio.h>" Do tell me if it works.

Comment: @Abhineet Now getting error C2065: 'FILE' undeclared identifier

Comment: http://codepad.org/2KGi8Pi6

Comment: As @icepack suggested, you have your error somewhere else. See this link:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewcf0002(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Abhineet I have referrred msdn already. Also, saw on codepad, it compiles fine. I am suspecting the error elsewhere as icepack. Here is the code http://codepad.org/Lv6fLeIH#line-19

Comment: I have pasted the code as-is

Comment: Only see line 156. I tried removing the _ character. Still it fails

Comment: argmatch.c
    ../gnu/argmatch.c(156) : error C2065: 'stderr' : undeclared identifier
    ../gnu/argmatch.c(161) : error C2065: 'stderr' : undeclared identifier
    ../gnu/argmatch.c(166) : error C2065: 'stderr' : undeclared identifier
    ../gnu/argmatch.c(168) : error C2065: 'stderr' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Disabled the warnings. Now getting 4 errors at stderr from line 156

Comment: Have you tried including <stddef.h> ?

Comment: http://codepad.org/THJ6mZay#line-53 I think now you can figure out the errors. :-D If it helps, do tell me and I will make it as an answer.

Comment: @Abhineet Thanks for looking into the code. But no, it still gives the same error. I am probably missing something elsewhere. Code appears to be all right.

Comment: @Abhineet I got the source of the problem here. Actually, I am trying to compile gnu libraries using MSVC. They have their own implementation of all the standard header file `stdio.h string.h errno.h` etc. The compiler was taking stdio.h from gnu code which is different. Deleted the std headers from code directory. errors gone. P.S. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294454/include-next-preprocessor-directive-causing-problems-in-msvc#comment21584481_15294454

Answer (score 16):

While stdio.h should work, sometimes you need to include stdlib.h as well.  Include the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Declare both of these includes at the TOP of the **same** .C file your argmatch_valid function above is defined.

My crystal ball suggests that the stdio.h you think you are including is getting wrapped by a comment or within another preprocessor section that is getting wiped out. Maybe you can post your entire source file. Someone will likely spot the real error.