# include_next preprocessor directive causing problems in MSVC

Tags: c, windows, gnu, visual-studio-2010

I know that inlcude_next happens to be GNU extension of the C preprocessor.
I am facing an issue compiling Gnu library code using MSVC. For instance, there is an stdio.h header file or rather `GNU-like <stdio.h>`. When compiled using MS compiler, I get `invalid preprocessor command 'include_next'` which is fine because there is nothing like a `#include_next` directive for windows. The main aim of doing #include_next being you would like to create a file called stdio.h in your project, and that would be included instead of the default header.

So, I tried 2 options:
1) Comment out this line `// #include_next <stdio.h>` in all the files.
2) Or replace #include_next by `#include <stdio.h>`.

I don't know if opting for 1) will cause any problems(linker errors at the end).
Regarding 2), I got `fatal error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024` which is also fine. For this, I would use `wrapper #ifndef` for the *include guards* or `# pragma once` directive.

Following are my concerns:

Do I need to write a statement like `#include <stdio>` or `#include "stdio.h"`inside the header file stdio.h? Will it make any sense when compiling for Windows. Won't I suffice with just doing `#include "stdio.h"` directly in all the source files where it needs, so that it would bypass the Visual C standard header and rather use mine? 
And, what might/might not happen if I omit the statement include_next in entirety?

My main aim being to successfully compile gnu libraries using MSVC.
Please correct me if I am missing something or perhaps throw more light on this topic.

Comment: "My aim being to successfully compile gnu libraries using MSVC" - see http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @roger_rowland I meant the code which I am having has include_next. They are not exact gnu libraries. I can use from the above link. but the application demands are different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither option 1 nor 2 are going to work. It is a header that wraps the system one. So if you comment it out, the system header won't get included and it's definitions will be missing. And if you change it to plain `#include`, it will include the same header again, causing infinite loop.

Boost uses

```
#include <../include/stdio.h>
```

this works on WinNT, because all the standard headers happen to be in directories called `include`. It also works on standard WinCE SDKs, but unfortunately does not work on all of them.

Comment: Nice kludge - #include_next is anyway [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Wrapper-Headers.html) as such.