# How to use Arduino with Microsoft Visual Studio ( Due to #include_next precompiler issues)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, arduino, gcc-extensions

In short,

I need to do this,

```
#include_next <limits.h>
```

however Visual Studio doesn't like this and complains,

```
Error   40  error C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'include_next'    c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\g++_arm_none_eabi\arm-none-eabi\include\limits.h  141 1   DataloggerFirmware (Visual Studio 2010)
```

I can't simply do

```
#include <limits.h>
```

there are too many files!!.

```
Error   9   error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024  c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\g++_arm_none_eabi\arm-none-eabi\include\limits.h  141 1   DataloggerFirmware (Visual Studio 2010)
```

Is there any work around??

Comment: Which version of C++ is `include_next` supported?  What does it do?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, It's a GCC extension. It basically just searches for the same file past the current one. For example, if you have a file with the same name as one in the standard library and want to include the standard library one in yours.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, what Chris said. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Wrapper-Headers.html

Comment: You are trying to compile arduino source in visual studio. Is it really supported?

Comment: @Slava Agreed! I'd suppose that VS cross compiling capabilities are pretty narrow. But I'd be proven wrong possibly :P ...

Comment: @Slava I've taken up this project from someone who recently left where I work. I am just following his documentation as best I can.

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest: Perhaps he left because he realised that he had agreed to do something that is not possible, and panicked rather than owning up to it. :)

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest Another explanation could be that your former colleague used VS just as IDE for code editing, but not for compilation actually (lookup for some extra makefiles or such stuff in the project directories). I've also seen such behavior on my worksite :P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ good idea. Maybe his documentation wording just lacks

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest if you try/have to make arduino work from Visual Studio I am afraid `include_next` will not be your hardest problem. You may want to read this article: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/VisualStudio

Comment: @Slava thankyou. I read this as a possible solution?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294454/include-next-preprocessor-directive-causing-problems-in-msvc

Comment: @Slava , on a side note I tried compiling the code on AtmelStudio6.1, and it gave me a error in cc1plus.exe =aurduino.h: No such file or directory. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest have you installed arduino plugin for AtmelStudio? https://gallery.atmel.com/Products/Details/20c64f07-4686-41fd-87f6-d841d568e8c5?p=6

Comment: @Slava installing Micro....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Posting here so maybe it helps someone else.

As I was most concerned with creating a Binary file for my Arduino board here are the steps.

### Step 1

Make sure you have installed a version of the Arduino software from this [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).

### Step 2

Install the Visual Micro Utility. Follow [this](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx) documentation carefully.

### Step 3

Fire up Visual Studio, after installation is complete. Follow the steps it suggests. Choosing the appropriate folder for where you installed the Arduino Package.

Restart Visual Studio. You should now see a Arduino row of options added to your Visual Studio tab (under the File save etc options).

Select the board type and other options, and build. Voilà you're done. [image]

Special shoot out to the people in the comments section.

Comment: Good answer thanks but no need to re-start visual studio after setting the Arduino ide location

Answer (score 1):

`#include_next` is a compiler extension (for example see [Why would one use #include_next in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261382/why-would-one-use-include-next-in-a-project)) and not part of the C++ language. As it's not part of the language your only real option (other than sticking with the original compiler that supports the extension) would be to restructure your code so that it doesn't use a user-defined file `limits.h`.

Comment: the code base is too large and has multiple dependencies in various places. I don't think that would be possible.

Comment: Then it's a shame the author of the codebase did not consider portability.

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest why do you have to compile it by VS rather than gcc-avr?